# How to get data from ReportViewer control

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdl

I have access to some RDL reports. I can use ReportViewer control in my app to display it, but How can I get data displayed in this report and put them into my database table?

Is it possible?

Comment: You have to set a ReportDataSource for the report. Essentially you retrieve the data from the database in the form of a DataSet, DataTable, or some other method and create a ReportDataSource by supplying its name (used in the RDL report) and the DataSet, DataTable, or whatever other method you used.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get data displayed in this report and put them into my database table?

Short answer is No.

Reports are a one way *data representation* in the form of a read-only *report* from a datasource. It is not a conduit back to a database or a new database due to the read-only aspect.

To get the data, you need to examine the report, determine how it accesses the data source and use that process to access the get data in your program.